# listbox selected items in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have listbox, button, and textbox controls in a Windows application. How can I display multiple selected values in a textbox.

this is my code

```
textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString();
```

but it display in textbox like this: (I select more than one item)

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+Selec.
```

please help me

Comment: @surya: then you should do the polite and proper thing and accept the best answer / the one that really solved you problem. To accept the answer, please click on the check mark to the left of the answer below the "0" with the up- and down-arrow. If someone helps you - please be so kind as to accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
string text = "";

foreach (System.Data.DataRowView item in listBox1.SelectedItems) {
    text += item.Row.Field<String>(0) + ", ";
}
textBox1.Text = text;
```

Comment: If there are many many elements, think about using StringBuilder as it's more efficient...

Comment: There's also a text = String.Join(" ", listBox1.SelectedItems);

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the collection of items. Something like:

```
textBox1.Text = "";
foreach (object o in listBox1.SelectedItems)
   textBox1.Text += (textBox1.Text == "" ? "" :", ") + o.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> The post is quite old but lacks a correct general answer which can
>   work regardless of the data-bound item type for example for `List<T>`,
>   `DataTable`, or can work regardless of setting or not setting
>   `DisplayMember`.

The correct way to get text of an item in a `ListBox` or a `ComboBox` is using [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

It doesn't matter what is the type of item, if you have used `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` it uses `DisplayMember` to return text, otherwise it uses `ToString` method of item.

For example, to get a comma-separated list of selected item texts:

```
var texts = this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
                .Select(x => this.listBox1.GetItemText(x));

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", texts));
```

**Note:** For those who are looking for selected item values rather that selected item texts regardless of the item type and the value member field, they use [`GetItemValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Actrually, if you know the type of object you input into ListBox, the selected item is that type, here is a sample:
Input List of FileInfo to ListBox:

```
        FileInfo[] lFInfo = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text).GetFiles();
        foreach (var i in lFInfo)
            lstFile.Items.Add(i);
```

A copy function to copy the selected files to path of textBox2.Text:

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      foreach (FileInfo i in lstFile.SelectedItems)
          File.Copy(i.FullName, Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, i.Name));
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**[ListBox.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28VS.85%29.aspx)**:  Returns a collection of the currently selected items.

Loop through the SelectedItems collection of the listbox.

```
foreach (ListItem liItem in ListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    // write your code.   
}
```

Comment: @rahul, there is no ListItem class in winforms like there is in webforms.