# Multi selection list box in WinForms

Tags: winforms, select, listbox

I am looking for way to implement multi selection enabled list box in windows forms C#. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: List boxes do this already.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420514/listbox-selected-items-in-winform

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just add a `ListBox` control and set the Property: `SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended`

Then you can get the selected items in: `ListBox1.SelectedItems`

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without pressing `Ctrl`? I mean to select a row by just clicking on the item

Comment: Yes. Override ListBox's  OnClick event.

Comment: Or, the even easier way: set SelectionMode to MultiSimple.