# Get the value for a listbox item by index

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, listbox

This must be very easy but I am stuck.
I have a listBox with X Items. Each Item has a text description (Which appears in the listBox) and its value(numerical). 
I want to be able to get the value property of an item, using the index number of the item.

Comment: WPF, WinForms, Silverlight or ASP.NET?

Comment: Add some tags detailing what you're using like Daniel Hilgarth said above.

Comment: Are you working on a _windows forms_ application??

Comment: The answer depends on setting of the listbox. but to have an independent answer, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834).

Answer (score 17):

It would be

```
String MyStr = ListBox.items[5].ToString();
```

Comment: Items may be `DataRowView` or a Complex Object or other types. Underlying value of an item should be calculated base on `ValueMember`.

Answer (score 13):

Here I can't see even a single correct answer for this question (in WinForms tag) and it's strange for such frequent question.

Items of a `ListBox` control may be `DataRowView`, Complex Objects, Anonymous types, primary types and other types. Underlying value of an item should be calculated base on `ValueMember`.

`ListBox` control has a `GetItemText` which helps you to get the item text regardless of the type of object you added as item. It really needs such `GetItemValue` method.

**GetItemValue Extension Method**

We can create `GetItemValue` [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to get item value which works like [`GetItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
public static class ListControlExtensions
{
    public static object GetItemValue(this ListControl list, object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(list.ValueMember))
            return item;

        var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item)[list.ValueMember];
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("item doesn't contain '{0}' property or column.",
                list.ValueMember));
        return property.GetValue(item);
    }
}
```

Using above method you don't need to worry about settings of `ListBox` and it will return expected `Value` for an item. It works with `List<T>`, `Array`, `ArrayList`, `DataTable`, List of Anonymous Types, list of primary types and all other lists which you can use as data source. Here is an example of usage:

```
//Gets underlying value at index 2 based on settings
this.listBox1.GetItemValue(this.listBox1.Items[2]);
```

Since we created the `GetItemValue` method as an extension method, when you want to use the method, don't forget to include the namespace which you put the class in.

This method is applicable on `ComboBox` and `CheckedListBox` too.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on a windows forms project you can try the following:

Add items to the `ListBox` as `KeyValuePair` objects:

```
listBox.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair(key, value);
```

Then you will be able to retrieve them the following way:

```
KeyValuePair keyValuePair = listBox.Items[index];
var value = keyValuePair.Value;
```

Comment: @tzam: I've edited my answer. It will work if you are using the described method ...

Comment: The listbox is databound, so it is populated automatically... Do you have any idea how it could work this way? 
Besides that, your answer works and was great help!!!

Comment: @tzam: Try to use `DictionaryItem` instead of `KeyValuePair` .

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a BindingSource with a SqlDataReader behind it and none of the above works for me.

Question for Microsoft:  Why does this work:

```
  ? lst.SelectedValue
```

But this doesn't?

```
   ? lst.Items[80].Value
```

I find I have to go back to to the BindingSource object, cast it as a System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord, and then refer to its column name:

```
   ? ((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)_bsBlocks[80])["BlockKey"]
```

Now that's just ridiculous.

Comment: Alternatively I guess I could iterate through the Items collection, selecting each item and then getting SelectedValue.  But I shouldn't have to do this, and it's a kludge anyway.

Comment: An Item in `Items` collection of a `ListBox` is of type object and it doesn't have a `Value` property. The item may be a `DataRowView`, a complex object or a primary type. The value should be calculated using `ValueMember` property, the same way `SelectedValue` works.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ListBox x = new ListBox();
x.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello", "1"));
x.Items.Add(new ListItem("Bye", "2"));

Console.Write(x.Items[0].Value);
```

Comment: As far as I know, `ListBox.Items` is of type `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection` which means `ListBox.Items[index]` is an Object which does not have a Value property !!

Comment: This was an answer for WebForms, as he is referring to Settings a Text and Value, that made me assume WebForms, not WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want the value of the first item.

```
ListBox list = new ListBox();
Console.Write(list.Items[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply try this
'listBox' is your list and 'yu' is a veriable to which the value on index 0 will be assigned

```
string yu = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(yu);
```

Comment: In fact at the best case it will return text for an item. Items may be `DataRowView` or a complex object or other types. The underlying value of an item should be calculated base on `ValueMember`.