# How to get selected index from selected value in combo box C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is there any built-in method for getting selected index from selected value in ComboBox control C#. If not, how can I built my own one

Thanks in advance

Comment: Old question, but needs a correct answer, regardless of the data source type (DataTable, Lits<T>, ...). Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826110/3110834).

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the SelectedIndex property.

```
int index = comboref.SelectedIndex
```

As you're looking for the index of a specific value not the selected one you can do

```
int index = comboref.Items.IndexOf("string");
```

and it will tell you which Index has "string" on the combobox

Comment: No, what I want is to get index from value. i.e: `int seletedIndex = comboBox.getIndexFromKnownSelectedValue(value)`

Comment: no, I have a value and I want a index corresponding to that value

Comment: Hope that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combobox1.Items.IndexOf("string")` which will return the index within the collection of the specified item

Or use `combobox1FindString("string")` or `findExactString("string")` which will return the **first** occurence of the specified item. You can also give it a second parameter corresponding to the `startIndex` to start searching from that index.

I Hope I answered your question !!

Answer (score 0):

> **OP:** What I want is to get index from value. i.e: int seletedIndex = comboBox.getIndexFromKnownSelectedValue(value)

**Get Item by Value** and **Get Index by Value**

You need to scan the items and for each item get the value based on the `SelectedValue` field and then get the index of item. To do so, you can use this [GetItemValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) extension method and get item and index this way:

```
//Load sample data
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
        .Select(x => new { Name = $"Product {x}", Id = x }).ToList();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Knows value
    var value = 3;

    //Find item based on value
    var item = comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
        .Where(x => comboBox1.GetItemValue(x).Equals(value))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    //Find index 
    var index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);

    //Set selected index
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no any built-in method for getting selected index from selected value in ComboBox control C#.
But you can create your own function to get the same.

**Usage:**

```
int index = CmbIdxFindByValue("YourValue", YourComboBox);
```

**Function:**

```
private int CmbIdxFindByValue(string text, ComboBox cmbCd)
{
    int c = 0;
    DataTable dtx = (DataTable)cmbCd.DataSource;
    if (dtx != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dx in dtx.Rows)
        {
            if (dx[cmbCd.ValueMember.ToString()].ToString() == text)
                return c;
            c++;
        }
        return -1;
    } else
        return -1;

}
```

Comment: While it may work in case the data source is data table, but for other cases it will not work. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) which shows how to get value from item. Then to find the item you can use such linq query:  `var item = comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
        .Where(x => (int)comboBox1.GetItemValue(x) == value)
        .FirstOrDefault();` and to get index `var index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Your solution was a great help.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Glad to hear that helped.