# Get index from Combobox based on ValueMember

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a Combobox that stores a `name` as DisplayMember and an `id` as ValueMember. On my database, I store only the `id`.

How can I set it to the correct index by `id`?

Example code:

```
Combobox.SelectedIndex = Combobox.FindByValueMember("10");
```

The best I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764755/how-to-get-selected-index-from-selected-value-in-combo-box-c-sharp/27764784) question, but the most voted answer did not undestand what the question was.

```
int index = comboref.Items.IndexOf("string");
```

Does not work, as it does not search by ValueMember.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558722/10723900) answers it but I'm wondering if there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Did you try this: `comboref.Items["string"]`, seems that is the [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160818/5533960)

Comment: Let me see if it works, I hadn't found that question

Comment: set `SelectedValue`. You don't need to find the index.

Comment: IMO, `SelectedValue` should be what you are looking for; however for learning purpose, I shared examples for setting `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` based  on the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to find the index based on the selected value, just set `SelectedValue`.

**Example 1 - Set SelectedValue**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
        .Select(x => new { Name = $"Product {x}", Id = x }).ToList();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedValue = 3;
}
```

While above example shows how to set the selection using the selected value, if for any reason you want to find the item or selected index based on the value, then you need to use this [GetItemValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) extension method and find the item base on that.

**Example 2 - Get Item by Value → Set SelectedItem**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = 3;
    var item = comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
        .Where(x => comboBox1.GetItemValue(x).Equals(value))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;
}
```

**Example 3- Get Index by Value → Set SelectdIndex**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = 3;
    var item = comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
        .Where(x => comboBox1.GetItemValue(x).Equals(value))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    var index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Setting SelectedValue worked for me, but not as suggested in the first example with an Int. I had to do `comboBox1.SelectedValue = value.ToString()` otherwise it would go null.

Comment: You're welcome. The type in my example is `int` so no need to `ToString`. It should follow the same type that you set in`ValueMember` field of the object in `DataSource`.

Comment: @JoãoNunes Set `comboBox1.DataSource = ...` last.