# Show ValueMember of CheckedListBox on item click

Tags: c#

I have a winform c# checkedlist box.  This checklist box is Databound.  It's Display Member contains names of student and valueMember contains their ID's.  From the checklistbox, when I check any item, I want it to show their corresponding ID as present in ValueMember.  At present in the ItemCheck event.  I am iterating all the checked items and showing their ValueMember.

Is it possible to get the ValueMember property without iterating through the list?  I would prefer a one or two line solution.

```
foreach (DataRowView view in chkLBoxNames.CheckedItems)
{
  MessageBox.Show(view[chkLBoxNames.ValueMember].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You can use [GetItemValue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) extension method.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to write this solution without sounding like a commercial, but try the free trial of Resharper.  You will get exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help, useless

Comment: @FredSmith Glad I could help