# How to get multiple selected values from listbox C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I am using a `Listbox` on my windows application. The listbox has a multi-selection option, which users select all the roles the new user will have.
My Listbox is bound to a dataset. The table is Roles, with an ID column and Description column.
When I bound the listbox, I chose the data source being the dataset, the display member to be the description, the value member being the ID and the selected value being the dataset - roles.frolesid[image]

Now when i loop through the listbox's selecteditems, i get only the first item's values etc...

I am trying to assign an int to the current selectedvalue, to get the ID to give to the user.

```
 int num = 0;
 foreach (var item2 in lstRoles.SelectedItems)
 {
      num = Convert.ToInt32(lstRoles.SelectedValue);
 }
```

So if I select 3 roles, for instance Administrator, Capturer and Assessor, I only see the Administrator value.

How do I loop and access the next item? I'm not even using

> item2 
>   in my code. Could this be utilised?

For instance:

[image]

First iteration:

[image]

And it just stays on that selected item, never moving to the next item.

Comment: You already use it. "lstRoles.SelectedItems". If you run the iteration until finished, you can see "Administrator, Assessor, Capturer"

Comment: not actually. when i go through, it stays on Administrator

Comment: try "lstRoles.SelectedItems.Count" , it must be 3

Comment: it is 3. but its not giving me anything else i could use. unless i do some if statements with the count?

Comment: lstRoles.SelectedItems[0] is your first selectedItem, then lstRoles.SelectedItems[1] is your second selectedItem, then lstRoles.SelectedItems[2] is your third selectedItem

Comment: eventually got it. Posted my answer. Thanks for the help, got me thinking on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it

```
            int num = 0;
            int count = fRoleIDs.Count;
            while (num != count)
            {
                var item = lstRoles.Items[num] as System.Data.DataRowView;
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Row.ItemArray[0]);
                num += 1;
            }
```

This goes into the listbox's items and according to the index, gets the item as a Row. This then gets me the itemarray, which is ID and Description {0,1}

Comment: Item of a `ListBox` control may be `DataRowView`, Complex Objects, Anonymous types, primary types and other types. Underlying value of an item should be calculated base on `ValueMember`.  You man find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To get list of selected values when the data source is a `DataTable`, you can use this code:

```
var selectedValues = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>()
                             .Select(dr => (int)(dr[listBox1.ValueMember]))
                             .ToList();
```

But in general Item of a `ListBox` control may be `DataRowView`, Complex Objects, Anonymous types, primary types and other types. Underlying value of an item should be calculated base on `ValueMember`.

If you are looking for a good solution which works with different settings and different data sources, you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) helpful. It contains an extension method which returns value of an item. It works like `GetItemText` method of `ListBox`.