# Can't get correct value from Item in CheckedBoxList

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

Given that I added an item to `CheckedListBox` this way:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add("ItemA");
```

And let's say that this is the only item in the control:

```
string s = checkedListBox1.GetItemText(0);
```

Now the value of s is `"0"` when I expect `"ItemA"`. Why can't I get correct value using `checkedListBox1.GetItemText(int itemIndex)` method?

Comment: Do you mean `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: While Reza's answer is right, I believe you can also use `checkedBoxList1.Items[0].ToString();` to get the text.

Comment: @Equalsk, you can unless you've set `DisplayMember`, as noted in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Equalsk [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) is more suitable, because it also supports `DispayMember` is is set.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the object which is an item of `CheckedListBox` to [`GetItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8):

```
MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.Items[0]);
```

Otherwise `GetItemText` returns `ToString` of passed object.

Comment: This answer is correct, but wow that's a weird API Microsoft provided.  Without seeing the method signature and documentation, I would have made the same assumption as the OP.

Comment: @adv12 The thing which is more strange to me is lack of [`GetItemValue`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) method in list controls (like `ListBox` or `CheckedListBox`) while IMO it should contain such method like `GetItemText`.

Comment: @adv12 Yeah, the API's kind of odd, not sure if this is an option for the OP, but I usually use `ListView`s https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx with `CheckBoxes` true instead of a `CheckedListBox`, I find a ListView to be easier to work with in most cases.

Comment: @jrh Yes, it could be an option, but `ListView` doesn't support data-binding and doesn't have support for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. I fixed the problem of not having `GetItemValue` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

Use `checkedListBox1.Items[0].ToString();` instead of `GetItemText()`

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494797/cant-get-correct-value-from-item-in-checkedboxlist/39494952#comment66307449_39494797).