# How to retrieve selected values for selected items in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I'm populating a ListBox in a WinForms application, this way:

```
listBoxUsers.DataSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
listBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBoxUsers.ValueMember = "Id";
```

how to retrieve the selected Ids when I'm setting the `SelectionMode` to `MultiSimple`
I want to do a `foreach` loop on them, like this:

```
foreach(var itemId in listBoxUsers.SelectedValues)//unfortunately not exist
{
    int id = int.Parse(itemId);
    // . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the type of items, you can use such code:

```
var selectedValues = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<User>().Select(x=>x.Id).ToList();
```

---

**Side Note:** The `ListBox` control lacks a [`GetItemValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) method. A method which should work like `GetItemText`, but for getting values. In the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834) I shared an extension method to get the value from an item. Using that extension method you can get selected values independent from type of items:

```
var selectedValues = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => listBox1.GetItemValue(x)).ToList();
```

If for some reason you are interested to have a text representation for selected values:

```
var txt = string.Join(",", selectedValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the SelectedItems property?

```
foreach (var item in listBoxUsers.SelectedItems)
```

{

}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in listBoxUsers.SelectedItems)
            {
              int id=int.parse(item[0].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: The items which the OP is using are of type `User`, they are not `DataRowView`.