# C# Unable to cast object of type 'TCSCapstone.frmInventory' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I'm trying to add up all the values in a `Listbox` which the `Listbox` is populated by the value of two other list boxes multiplied together. It's essentially a sum of a `Listbox`.

I keep getting an error and I looked it up and everyone else has similar issues with similar problems. It has something to do with the `ToInt32` or the `ToString`, I just cannot fix it. Whenever I click my button to load the `Listbox` which executes that loop, it gives me the error.

Please help, this is all I need left.

```
         int i = 0, result = 0;
         while (i < lstTotalPrices.Items.Count)
         {
             result += Convert.ToInt32(lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]);
         }

         txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Comment: can you post the exact error message ..

Comment: Assuming the error is on the line with Items[i++] on it. Have you checked that Items is returning what you ate expecting (from your code it looks like you're expecting a string). Now not saying its not as I am on my phone and don't have access to a coding environment but worth a check.

Comment: @Andrew Harris I gave that a try, 
    lstTotalPrices.GetItemValue(lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]‌​); 
Instead of my original line but I am getting an error that says: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'GetItemValue' and no extension method... And it goes on, perhaps I'm missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Sorry Luke I dumped that as i only half read something else. Is there a Value property? Try debugging var item = lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]; and see what type of object you get back. It won't be a primitive type that you're expecting.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "value property? As in the .Value property or the actual value of the lstTotalPrices?

Comment: I'm going to jump on the laptop but in the meantime see if this helps and also note my updated last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504336/get-the-value-for-a-listbox-item-by-index

Comment: I apologize for my inexperience with debugging/coding, but how do I obtain the value? I tried Debugging (F5) and noticed it broke at this exact line but I couldn't find the value it had.

Comment: How are you populating the list box items?

Comment: I use a List<> that uses FileReader and StreamReader to obtain data from pre-made text files, it splits those into three list boxes. Two of them are an integer list box and the other is a decimal list box. The fourth listbox (which is totalPrice the one involved) is the second and third listbox multiplied together. My goal is to add the entire fourh listbox together and put the total number in a text box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143933/discussion-between-andrew-harris-and-luke-sitler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments and chat this should work:

```
int i = 0; 
decimal result = 0; 
while (i < lstTotalPrices.Items.Count) 
{ 
    result += ((frmInventory)lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]).TotalPrice; 
}
```

Although a tidier solution would be

```
int i = 0;
decimal result = 0;

foreach (var item in lstTotalPrices.Items)
{
    result += item.TotalPrice;
}
```

Comment: This is the one that worked! I'll try the second one later, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]` is not convertible to an integer using `Convert.ToInt32()` So better you convert them to a string and then pass those values to `ToInt32()`, try the following:

```
 result += Convert.ToInt32(lstTotalPrices.Items[i++].ToString());
```

You can use `int.TryParse()` for this conversion, instead for `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: I tried adding .ToString() to the end and it gave me the exact error still. I then kept the .ToString() and then replaced the Convert.ToInt32 with int.TryParse() but it then gave me an error: No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 argument. Here's my exact line I tried:                  result += int.TryParse(lstTotalPrices.Items[i++].ToString());

Comment: This missed the point that Items[] doesnt return the value, it returns the underlying List Item object.

Comment: What is the value you are getting through `lstTotalPrices.Items[i++]`

Comment: Not sure how to check the actual value, but if you're asking what I'm trying to do, I'm attempting to get the value of each individual item then add them up. If that's not what you were asking sorry, trying to answer as quickly as possible. The lstTotalPrice is filled with about 7 or 8 decimal values if that helps