# Looking to search a listBox in C# that is populated by an inputFile to see if it contains a string that is input by a user into textbox

Tags: c#

This is a problem I am having in C# Visual studio 2019, and it should be relatively simple for somebody more experienced to help me, and I appreciate all help. I'm going crazy trying to figure this out! I have two listboxes, one called boyBox and one called GirlBox. I used to populate the listboxes with the text files:

```
private void populateBoys()
 {
            //Try to access the file, if problems arise an error message will show
            try
            {
                //Declare object to access file
                StreamReader inputFile;
                inputFile = File.OpenText("..\\..\\BoyNames.txt");

                //Loop to run through all items in the text file
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //read lines from the file and add to the listbox
                    boyBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void populateGirls()
        {
            //Try to access the file, if problems arise an error message will show
            try
            {
                //Declare object to access file
                StreamReader inputFile;
                inputFile = File.OpenText("..\\..\\GirlNames.txt");

                //Loop to run through all items in the text file
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //read lines from the file and add to the listbox
                    girlBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

To populate the listboxes with a list of popular boy and girl names called BoyNames.txt and GirlNames.txt. This seems simple enough, but I am being driven insane trying to find something that works for me to simply type a name into a textbox and have the program tell me if the name was in the list or not. The closest I got was :

```
private void boyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string boyname = boyBox2.Text;
    bool found = false;
    for(int n = 0; n < boyBox.Items.Count; n++)
    {
        if (boyBox.Items[n] == boyname)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        MessageBox.Show("popular");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("not popular");

}
```

But it just says "Not Popular" even if I typed one of the names that IS in the list into the textbox "boyBox2". The listbox is "boyBox". I'm just trying to find help to figure out what code I can use to get it to work for letting me know if what I type into the textbox "boyBox2" is a name that is in the listbox/file or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following reads a file with girl names into a BindingList<GirlName>
which becomes the data source of a BindingSource which is set to a ListBox.

In a TextBox TextChanged event a lambda statement does a like/starts-with on names in the ListBox. If the TextBox is empty the filter is removed.

Containers for names

```
public class NameBase
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => DisplayText;
}

public class GirlName : NameBase { }
public class BoyName : NameBase { }
```

Classes for taking a raw text file with girl names to a sorted list of girl names in a new file.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string sender) 
        => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sender) ? 
            sender : 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sender.ToLower());
}

public class FileOperations
{

    public static string _fileName => "gNames.txt";
    public static bool GirlFileExits => File.Exists(_fileName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to create a list of names without extra data
    /// along with proper casing names
    /// </summary>
    public static void CreateGirlFile()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        /*
         * girlnames.txt came from
         * https://github.com/SocialHarvest/harvester/blob/master/data/census-female-names.csv
         * populated via raw button, copied to girlnames.txt, set copy to output directory if newer
         */
        var names = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);

        /*
         * assumes comma delimited with at least one item
         */
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            string[] lineSplit = name.Split(',');
            list.Add(lineSplit[0].ToTitleCase());
        }

        list = list.OrderBy(item => item).ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines(_fileName, list.ToArray());
    }

    public static List<GirlName> ReadGirlNames()
    {
        List<GirlName> names = new List<GirlName>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);
        
        for (int index = 0; index < lines.Length -1; index++)
        {
            names.Add(new GirlName() {Index = index, DisplayText = lines[index]});
        }

        return names;
    }
}
```

Form has a ListBox and TextBox which does a starts-with, could also be a contains or ends-with.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource _girlNamesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private BindingList<GirlName> _girlsNamesBindingList;  

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        Shown += OnShown;
        SearchTextBox.TextChanged += SearchTextBoxOnTextChanged;
    }

    private void SearchTextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_girlNamesBindingSource == null) return;

        List<GirlName> filtered = _girlsNamesBindingList.Where(nameItem => 
            nameItem.DisplayText.StartsWith(
                SearchTextBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

        _girlNamesBindingSource.DataSource = filtered;

    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!FileOperations.GirlFileExits)
        {
            FileOperations.CreateGirlFile();
        }
        
        _girlsNamesBindingList = new BindingList<GirlName>(FileOperations.ReadGirlNames());
        _girlNamesBindingSource.DataSource = _girlsNamesBindingList;
        GirlsNameListBox.DataSource = _girlNamesBindingSource;

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you try to compare BETWEEN `Item` and `string value` and, you must compare BETWEEN the `Item's value` and the `string value` so, the code must be like so

```cs
private void boyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string boyname = boyBox2.Text;
    bool found = false;
    for(int n = 0; n < boyBox.Items.Count; n++)
    {
        if (boyBox.Items[n].Value == boyname)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        MessageBox.Show("popular");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("not popular");

}
```

**OR**

You must convert the `Item` to `string` using `ToString()` method so, the code must be like so

```cs
private void boyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string boyname = boyBox2.Text;
    bool found = false;
    for(int n = 0; n < boyBox.Items.Count; n++)
    {
        if (boyBox.Items[n].ToString() == boyname)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        MessageBox.Show("popular");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("not popular");

}
```

You can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6504336/11019205) also

Comment: the .ToString() method worked, thank you!