# Unable to get LIstBoxItem from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am unable to get `ListBoxItem` from `ListBox`. I have created `ListBox` dynamically; it is not in `XAML`. I just set `ItemsSource` and I have values in all the items but cannot access/convert each item as `ListBoxItem`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.Items[i]);
                // item is null after above statement
            }
```

**Note**: I just checked 'listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status' . listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status is 'notStarted'.

What to do now?

Comment: can you post your XAML too

Comment: When are you running this? If you're running it when the application starts up, you need to wait for the containers to be generated first before you can reference them like that.

Comment: I have created ListBox dynamically. All other work with ListBox is going well .

Comment: items count is greater than 1 and correct.

Comment: question updated .please have a look.

Comment: Can anyone please simply tell me how to generate/start 'listBox.ItemContainerGenerator'?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are not giving WPF enough time to render the `<ListBoxItem>` objects before calling your method.

A common way of accessing the `ListBoxItems` right after its `Items` property is set is to use the `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event, like this:

```
void MyConstructor()
{
    listBox.ItemsSource = someCollection;

    listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += 
        ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If containers have been generated
    if (listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == 
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // Remove event
        listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= 
            ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;

        // Do whatever here
        foreach(var item in listBox.Items)
        {
            var item = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            // do whatever you want with the item
        }

    }
}
```

WPF runs code at different [DispatcherPriorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx). Code run in the constructor or on load is run at `Normal` priority, while the generation of `ListBoxItem` objects doesn't occur until `Render` priority, which runs after all Normal priority items have finished running.

You could alternatively use the Dispatcher to run your code at a later dispatcher priority than `Render` as well.

Comment: But what if it's virtualized? It hasn't realized every listbox item :D

Comment: I just checked 'listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status' . listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status is 'notstarted'

Comment: @Ahsan Yes, if you want you can write the `ItemContainerGenerator.Status` to the Debug window in the `StatusChanged` event, and you will see the order of events that the `ItemContainerGenerator` goes through.

Comment: Can you please simply tell me how to generate/start 'listBox.ItemContainerGenerator'?

Comment: @lll:Yes it is virtuallized as listbox does not exist physically in XAML. It is just in code. Can youplease simply tell me how to generate/start 'listBox.ItemContainerGenerator'?

Comment: @Ahsan It starts automatically when WPF tries to render the items contained in `ListBox.Items`. If you're having problems with this, perhaps you can edit your question to share the code you're using to create and populate your ListBox?

Comment: @Ill If its virtualized, then you really shouldn't be referencing the `<ListBoxItem>` object anyways since a virtualized container won't create a `<ListBoxItem>` for every object, and forcing it to do something like this would probably be very bad for performance :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52127/discussion-between-ahsan-and-rachel)

Comment: @Rachel What if I have 1,000,000 items and there is a requirement that when it loads it should scroll to 900,000,000 and I have to modify the a dependency property to it?

Comment: @Ill Well for one, there wouldn't be a 900,000,000th item in a set of 1,000,000 items :) But I'm fairly sure you can set a scroll position without looping through every single item (I want to say it's `.ScrollIntoView(item)`, but I'm not positive). If you want to set a DP on that specific item, it should be set on the data object this list is bound to and the property bound to the UI. You should not be accessing the UI component for the object to set that property, as it can't be guartenteed that the data object displayed in that UI object will be the same at all times with virtualization

Answer (score -2):

Why are you casting the `listbox` to a `listboxitem`?

Here is a simular question about getting the selected items
[listbox selected items in winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420514/listbox-selected-items-in-winform)

You should be able to get the item by it's index

```
ListBox1.Items.Item(index)
```

Comment: WPF does not work the same way as Winforms. The items stored in `.Items` is not a list of `ListBoxItem` objects, but is instead a list of data objects